# Identify the workgroup MDW

Tags: ms-access, vba, mdw

In Microsoft Access, can you have Visual Basic identify what Workgroup you are using?

I find that new profiles need to be linked to the existing workgroup.  Sometimes if the server crashes, Access doesn't find the workgroup and resets to the local workgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DAO.DBEngine` object provides `SystemDB` property.  You can retrieve the value of that property from VBA.  Here's an example from the Immediate window.

```vb
? SystemDB
C:\Users\hans\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access\System.mdw
```

Comment: Cool. that works... half the time.  Do I need a reference?  I have a bunch of Databases.  Half of them show the path & Workgroup.  the other half shows blank (no length string).

When the database opens and opens the main menu (form), I implimented an If-Then: comparing the SystemDB with the correct path to my MDW.  if they don't match, then I show an error "You are in wrong workgroup" and quit the app. (else let them continue). Not fully implimented yet, but on 1 database it did work.  Thank you!

Comment: If it was a reference issue, I don't think it would work even half the time. I didn't know it was possible for `SystemDB` to return an empty string.  Are those ADP (Access Data Project) databases?

Comment: Re References: Since I have multiple databases, each one may have different references.
Re: ADP, no they are not.  My understanding is ADP is Access front-end and SQL backend.  We do have Access Front-end and Access back-end.

Comment: Its not working.  I created a new database with 1 form.  when the form opens, it has a message box to show the results of "systemdb".  
SO THEN... I'm part of a workgroup.  I open the database, it asks for a username and password. I enter that.  I Open the form, and a messagebox appears, but it is empty.  Any thoughts? why wouldn't systemdb return the workgroup path?

Comment: Instead of SystemDB, should I use DBEngine.systemdb?

Comment: You can try that but my best guess is it won't make any difference.  What do you get in the Immediate window with `? CurrentUser` ... that should give you the name of the Access workgroup account you supplied when logging in.

Comment: it didn't make a difference :(  I did ? currentuser and it came up correctly. then i did (immediately) ? systemdb.  it came up blank! arg!