# Missing .mdw file when importing Access DB to SQL Import/Export Wizard

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, import, database-migration

I am in the process of migrating an Access Database to an SQL Server 2016 Database. For this I am using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

[image]

The username is set to "admin" by default and I have provided the correct password. I can open the .mdb file just fine with Access 2016. When I click "Next" I receive this error:

[image]

I don't have an .mdw file in the folder, but I know the right credentials. How can I gain permission to import the database?

Answer (score 2):

If you've got an Access file with user-level security (secured with an `.mdw` file), you will need the file to work with it.

Since you're apparently able to login to the database, you're probably using the system workgroup.

As posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064762/identify-the-workgroup-mdw) by [HansUp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77335/hansup), you can identify the location of the workgroup file by typing `?SystemDb` in the immediate window

Without the `.mdw` file, there's no way to import the database (outside of hacking into it, that is)